# Invert Binary Tree: how to swap correctly entire left tree and right tree

Tags: go, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am confused how to swap binary tree correctly in golang.
Let say we have below BST

```
Input BST1
     1
    / \
   2   3
  / \  / \
 4  5 6   7
/ \
8  9

...
output BST2
     1
    / \
   3   2
  / \  / \
 7  6 5   4
         / \
        9   8

...
Why not this? BST3
     1
    / \
   3   2
  / \  / \
 5  4 7   6
/ \
9  8
```

I have figured out below code will output correct answer, and I understand swapping 2 and 3 works since tree is standing at 1 in the first place. However, when we start recursion, we shift our `tree` to the left and now there is no way to swap left tree's `4` and right tree `7`, for example. Since every time we go through recursion (inside of `if tree.Left != nil`, we shift our node to left, I am not sure why we can swap left tree side (like 4) node and right side (7) node. As far as my current understanding, BST3` seems to be the correct output...

```
type BinaryTree struct {
    Value int

    Left  *BinaryTree
    Right *BinaryTree
}

func (tree *BinaryTree) InvertBinaryTree() {
    
    tree.Left, tree.Right = tree.Right, tree.Left
    if tree.Left != nil{
        tree.left.InvertBinaryTree
    }
    if tree.Right != nil {
        tree.Right.InvertBinaryTree
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're swapping the *nodes*, not the values they contain. As such, all of the children come with. After you swap the root's children, the children of "2" will still be 4 and 5 (and once you swap that node's children, they will be 5 and 4). You're "re-wiring" the whole structure, not picking up the numbers and putting them down in new places within the same structure.

Comment: Thank you！As you explained, I thought `tree.Left, tree.Right = tree.Right, tree.Left` is swapping the value but actually _nodes_ (with children). I now understand how everything works.